# Formatting using a Raid driver

Tags: raid

Newbie here.
This might be a terrible question, I wanted to format a PC from Windows XP to 7 but when I reached the hdd partition there wasn't anything there, I was told I needed a Raid driver so I tried to look around according to the specifications but I haven't found one that works on my computer yet, while at it, I went in the Bios and changed from IDE to Raid. 
My computer is a bit old but it's a HighScreen that has the XP Version 32-bit.
Can anyone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You would only need a RAID driver if your machine had more than one drive and they were in a RAID array that was plugged into a RAID controller and used a form of RAID which is only for performance (i.e. Raid 0) and not just mirroring the drives.

The short version is that RAID lets two drives be read as one volume, but not for the purposes of increased capacity.  It was (note, I said was) a way to enhance performance on storage media by either placing 2-*n* drives in an array so you can either read all of the drives at once to load things faster, mirror the drives in case something breaks so you don't risk data loss, or combinations of both.  SSDs and cheap backup media have nearly supplanted this technology, and it's not nearly as popular; RAID-0 has almost zero performance benefit to an SSD array, and cloud storage make personal use RAID mirroring less attractive.

Your drivers may be found by searching for Vobis, a German company that manufactured the PCs that were then sold under the Highscreen brand.  Now Highscreen just sells Russian phones, which is probably part of your frustration.

If you don't mind wiping the drives (and indeed you may have to, if they were in RAID 0) then you can tell Win7 setup to create the partition by booting the machine with the Win7 disk in the drive.  It will blow away the data already on the drive and let you install Windows.   If you have two drives that were in RAID, you can just wipe the other drive and use it for storage.

Note that you should probably change your BIOS settings from RAID back to IDE to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and explanation, it really helped me out!